# Better Way to Build jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

I am utilizing jQuery UI Tabs in an ASP.NET MVC 2 web application. One part of the application requires that I do error checking when I switch away from the tab.  I am doing that via this script within the aspx file that contains the tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            cache: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
                switch ($tabs.tabs('option', 'selected')) {
                    case 0:
                        $.post("User/Personal", $("#PersonalForm").serialize(), function (data, success) {
                            if (success) {
                                $("#PersonalForm").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        $.post("User/Account", $("#AccountForm").serialize(), function (data, success) {
                            if (success) {
                                $("#AccountForm").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            },
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We will fix this as soon as possible.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are additional switch statements (removed for brevity).  Basically, this code allows the MVC validation to occur on the tabs via data annotations - works very nicely.  In any case, I was wondering if it is possible to have this code "generated" based on whatever tabs I have within my document.  (If it isn't, I basically have to code ever case statement within the switch statement by hand, which seems kind of a waste.)

Also, as a side note, I am using ASP controls for each tab to hold the various data (which is also where the individual forms reside).  That may make a difference to the solution.

Comment: Are all the tabs' content of the same type, e.g. containing a form (`PersonalForm`, `AccountForm`) etc, and that form's `action` points to where the `$.post()` should be sent for validation?

Comment: @Simen - Each tab contains one of the forms and the collection of tabs represents an entire user. (You select a user on a previous page and you get a series of tabs allowing you to enter a user.)  When I send the individual forms, it corresponds to a method within the controller class (there is one method per form within the tab). Does that clarify things?

Comment: Somewhat - see my answer and whether or not it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code, when the user leaves a tab, goes through each form on the tab you're leaving and sends an ajax request as in your code. The difference is that it figures out where to send it based on the form's `action` attribute instead of having to specify this in the switch statement. This means `PersonalForm`'s action attribute has to be `User/Personal` and so on.

```
select: function(e, ui) {
    var tab_index = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
    var panel_id = $("ul li a:eq(" + tab_index + ")", this).attr("href");
    var panel = $(panel_id); //the content of the tab

    //For each form in the panel, submit it via AJAX and update its html according to the answer
    $(panel).find("form").each(function() {
        var that = this;
        $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data, success) {
            if (success) {
                $(that).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Of course, if you have no more than one form on the page you can skip the `each` and if there are only certain forms that should be submitted this way, you can add a class to them to filter the selection

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was going for. Thank you for your help. I've been learning jQuery and I can see why it is so darn popular. (Your solution here helped me to solve another jQuery problem I was having, too.)